# Apache redirect ServerAlias to ServerName

Tags: apache, ssl-certificate

I installed an SSL certificate through Let's Encrypt. Everything is great except for some variations of my domain I'm getting a message from my browser that "Your connection is not private". I assume that's because I'm only redirecting traffic to the https version of the url and not to my canonical url (ServerName).

Here's the setup of my apache file. On port 80 there are some redirects that forward traffic to port 443.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAlias dev.example.com

    [... some other stuff... ]

    RewriteEngine On
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/serviam2/access.log combined
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =dev.example.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

**Here's the important part:**
All traffic gets redirected to the 443 version (which is good) but I also want all the ServerAlias's to redirect to the ServerName.

So... http://dev.example.com should redirect to https://example.com

Also, https://dev.example.com should redirect to https://example.com

I'm not an apache kung fu master and am struggling getting this to fit by modifying the current setup.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `%{SERVER_NAME}` in `RewriteRule` to your target domain like:

```
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```